# How to write a function to get the x-value which yield the maximum Y in a loess smooth?

Tags: r

does anyone can help to write a function which can return the x value of the loess smooth? I did like follows, but seems wrong. What I am want to get is the x-value, which yield the maximum Y in the loess function. Thanks in advance.

```
  myFmsy<-function(x,y){
  model <- loess(y ~ x,span = 0.4)
   return(x[which(y==max(y))])
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are fitting a model and then not using it at all.
The return value of `loess` is a list (of class `"loess"`) with a member `fitted`. This is the vector where you want to find the maximum.

```
myFmsy <- function(x, y){
    model <- loess(y ~ x,span = 0.4)
    yfit <- model$fitted
    x[which(yfit == max(yfit))]
}

set.seed(6589)    # Make the results reproducible
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100)

myFmsy(x, y)
#[1] -0.938093
```

There might be cases where due to floating-point issues several values are close to each other, whithin a given tolerance. The following function checks this and also returns the fitted `y` and the index `ix` of where it can be found.

```
myFmsy2 <- function(x, y, tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.5){
    model <- loess(y ~ x,span = 0.4)
    yfit <- model$fitted
    inx <- which(abs(yfit - max(yfit)) < tol)
    list(x = x[inx], y.fitted = yfit[inx], ix = inx)
}

myFmsy2(x, y)
#$`x`
#[1] -0.938093
#
#$y.fitted
#[1] 0.5046313
#
#$ix
#[1] 48
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, Rui Barradas. However, I tried my own case, it didn't return the right value. I don't know what's the problem.

Comment: @Oscar-fr Can you post your data in the question, please? Just enough to reproduce the problem. Anyway, I have edited the answer making it more complete.

Comment: thanks a lot for your kindly assistance. The second one works very well in my case.